# Min and Max length for form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to set a min and max length of 15 numbers (numbers only) in my form field?

I've tried:

```
pattern".{15,15}"
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aScpD/2/

Answer (score 7):

Try

`\d` --> for numbers

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/hxf5B/)

```
pattern="\d{15,15}"
```

---

Update as commented by [s1lence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823963/s1lence)

```
pattern="\d{15}"
```

---

Update to set **Custom validation message**

Add this attribute to input field

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('15 digit number needed')"
```

---

Use as commented by [Jukka K. Korpela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084437/jukka-k-korpela) (check above fiddle for working demo)

```
title="Exactly 15 digits"
```

Comment: You can also just use `{15}`

Comment: @s1lence Ty added it to answer . I need  to revise back regex .It's been very long time not in touch with it.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) `setCustomValidity`, you should set e.g. `title="Exactly 15 digits"`.

Comment: Your code works fine in Chrome but when I tried it in Internet Explorer 10 it didn't. How can I fix this problem? Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wGwB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pattern = /[0-9]{15}/
```

- `[0-9]` match a number (safer than `\d` because `\d` matches also
  foreign number)
  **Edit:** According to Bergi, it's not true in JS, but it's still valid in a lot of Perl RegEx implementations.
- `{15}` is similar to `{15, 15}`.

Comment: "*\d matches also foreign number*" - where did you get that? Not in JS/HTML5

Comment: That's the way perl regex works, but know you say it, I'm not totally sure it's also true in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this.

```
<input title="requires exactly 15 digits" maxlength="15" pattern=".{15}" required />
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aScpD/3/)

Comment: The `title` attribute value here is seriously misleading, since the `pattern` attribute requires *exactly* 15 characters.